# appcfg.py and pre-release sdk issue

Tags: google-app-engine

Downloaded python v 1.6.4  of sdk and get following message when running local devserver:

INFO     2012-04-01 20:08:10,177 appcfg.py:582] Checking for updates to the SDK.

INFO     2012-04-01 20:08:11,660 appcfg.py:616] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.

Re-installed after unistalling both sdk and python 2.7 used fresh download multiple times issue repeats. Also unable to upload an application using appcfg.py

Command typed appcfg.py update appdrectory/

and it spits out standard text

Usage: appcfg.py [options]

Action must be one of:
  backends: Perform a backend action.
  backends configure: Reconfigure a backend without stopping it.
.....

Suspect is linked to fact that have pre-release appcfg.py

How to un-isntall pre-release sdk and put in latest release sdk  Is something special to be done.?

Comment: Or show us exactly what you're typing.

Comment: Since you've installed the SDK on Windows, have you tried the 'Deploy' option from the graphical interface? Does that work?

Comment: Issue was resolved not sure how but Uninstalled Python 2.7 re-installed python 2.5 and then python 2.7 and used command - c:/Python27/python "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appfg.py" update src/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should be: `python appcfg.py update <directory>`.

Is this what you have done?

Comment: yes appcfg.py update src/  (where src is directory having the app.yaml file)

Comment: Have you put `python` in front? (Although you shouldn't get that error otherwise. But you seem to be skipping that.)

Comment: that is not needed if have done appropriate file associations in windows